# Alternative to Symfony's "Collection" constraint

Tags: php, symfony, validation, annotations, fosrestbundle

I have a FOSRestBundle annotation on an existing controller that works well. It takes in a collection of nested JSON objects. Like this:

```
 use Symfony\Component\Validator\Constraints;
 
 ...
 
 * @Rest\RequestParam(
 *     name="forumsToCreate",
 *     key="forumsToCreate",
 *     strict=true,
 *     nullable=true,
 *     description="Array of objects [{ adminEmail: 'test@mail.com', forumName: 'my forum name', topic: 'baking'}]
 * (email is mandatory when sending forumsToCreate)",
 *     requirements=@Constraints\Collection(
 *         fields={
 *             "adminEmail": @Constraints\Required({@Constraints\NotBlank, @Constraints\Email}),
 *             "forumName" : @Constraints\Optional({@Constraints\NotBlank, @Constraints\Length(max="255")}),
 *             "topic": @Constraints\Optional({@Constraints\NotBlank, @Constraints\Length(max="255")}),
 *         },
 *     ),
 *     map = true
 * )
```

The `Collection` constratint has been working well so far, but now I want to have a new controller take in data for just *one* nested forum object, rather than an array of objects. Is there a different constraint I should use?

===

Clarification: I still want to be able to have other top-level params on this controller. But I want the "forum" param to be a single nested JSON object containing email, name and topic fields, rather than a collection of forum objects.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you want to apply the previous annotation to a Controller that takes only one forum object you have to put:

```
map = false
```

To understand why, just look at `AbstractScalarParam` (parent class of `RequestParam`) where you can see that `$this->map === true` implies that the constraint specified in the annotation will be applied to every item of the input (which is considered an array). If `map` is false the constraint is directly applied to the input.

Pay attention that the constraint called `Collection` can create misunderstandings: its goal it's not to validate a list (or a collection) but to validate an associative array by specifying a rule for each key of the array.
Look here to get some more info: https://symfony.com/doc/current/validation/raw_values.html

If you need to apply a constraint to a list of values, you need to use the constraint called `All`. See the following example.

To validate this array:

```
$input = [
    'email' => 'test@email.tld',
    'tags' => [
        [
            'slug' => 'symfony_doc',
            'label' => 'symfony doc',
        ],
    ],
];
```

You need these constraints:

```
$constraint = new Assert\Collection([
    // the keys correspond to the keys in the input array
    'email' => new Assert\Email(),
    'tags' => new Assert\Optional([
        new Assert\Type('array'),
        new Assert\Count(['min' => 1]),
        new Assert\All([
            new Assert\Collection([
                'slug' => [
                    new Assert\NotBlank(),
                    new Assert\Type(['type' => 'string']),
                ],
                'label' => [
                    new Assert\NotBlank(),
                ],
            ])
        ]),
    ]),
]);
```

Comment: Thanks, Luigi! This was a great explanation.

Answer (score 0):

Action annotations

```php
/**
 * ...
 * @RequestParam(name="adminEmail", requirements={@Constraints\NotBlank, @Constraints\Email})
 * @RequestParam(name="forumName", requirements={@Constraints\NotBlank, @Constraints\Length(max="255")})
 * @RequestParam(name="topic", requirements={@Constraints\NotBlank, @Constraints\Length(max="255")})
 */
```

Request body

```
{
    "adminEmail": "qwe@qwe.com",
    "forumName": "qwe",     
    "topic": "qwe"     
}
```

Comment: Thank you for your answer! I added a clarification to the question, since I see you added a bunch of top-level params. What I would like to be able to do is to have a single "forum" param that takes a single *nested* JSON object. Sorry for the mixup.